# JS is not executing rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I try to display a view in a modal but i dont know why my JS is not executing, i saw similar questions about it but it doesnt solve my issue,

My link

```
def create
    document = Document.find(params[:document_id])
    order  = Order.create!(doc_sku: document.doc_sku, amount: document.price, state: 'pending')

    redirect_to new_order_payment_path(order, format: :js, remote: true)
  end
```

controller:

```
def new
    @document = Document.last
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript'}
    end
  end
```

new.js.erb

```
$("#newModal .modal-content").html('<%= j render "payments/form" %>');
  $("#newModal").modal();
```

I test it with a simple `alert` but nothing change

In my log

```
Processing by PaymentsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"remote"=>"true", "order_id"=>"35"}
```

I dont have warnings/errors in the network or console of my browser

Comment: I think the problem here is in `render layout: false`.
Are you sure that you need it? Can you try to remove it?

Comment: I remove it but nothing change @AlexeySuslyakov

Comment: @AntoineWako what is the flow of UI you want to achieve? Do you want to `create some model` modal to be showed by clicking somewhere on the page?

Comment: @AntoineWako then I suggest you to debug it at the network level to determine whether the problem on the frontend or on the back. What your server returns in the response?

Comment: @AntoineWako And one more suggestion: can you try again with the empty block `format.js {}`?

Comment: I want display my new payment view in a modal @nattfodd

Comment: I dont see errors in the server returns

Comment: I tried but nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content type is wrong. Change render to just.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Should work.